# How to unpivot multi indexed data from excel file

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the Excel file I have:

[Excel table][1]
1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/krzuh.png

```
        FY20  FY20  ..FY21   FY21   
        P01   P02   … P01    P02
```

SCENARIO_1  CAD  1.00    1.00    1.00
SCENARIO_1  CAD  0.00    0.00    0.00
SCENARIO_1  CAD  0.00    0.00    0.00
SCENARIO_1  CAD  0.01    0.01    0.01
SCENARIO_1  CAD  0.07    0.07    0.07

I want this to be transformed in a table like this on Python:

SCENARIO_1  **CAD   FY20**  P01  1.00    1.00    1.00
SCENARIO_1  **CAD   FY20**  P02  0.00    0.00    0.00
SCENARIO_1  **CAD   FY21**  P03  0.00    0.00    0.00
SCENARIO_1  **CAD   FY21**  P04  0.01    0.01    0.01

I would appreciate any help.

Leo

Comment: It would drastically improve the chances of you getting an answer if you gave people the code to setup this problem and print the output.

Comment: `df.stack(level=[0,1])`could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks guys. I found a way to work using melt.